# Kotlin: Is it possible to pass two 'this' in a function?

Tags: android, kotlin

With the below code I'm getting the following error: "Suspend function 'getSomethingFromAPI' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function.", which is current. getSomethingFromAPI is indeed a suspend function of the ViewModel.

```
    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(CallVM::class.java)

        viewModel.applyLaunch {
            this.getSomethingFromAPI()
        }
    }

   fun <T: ViewModel> T.applyLaunch(block: T.() -> Unit)
           = apply { viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { block() } }
```

As you can see though, in the applelaunch function I am executing getSomethingFromAPI inside of a coroutine (launch), but this information is lost. Is there any way to preserve it and keep T as ViewModel at the same time?

To be more specific, is it possible to have a shortcut function that implements two first lines of the below code?

```
        viewModel.apply {
            viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                 getSomethingFromAPI()
        }
```

getSomethingFromAPI above sees both 'this' (ViewModel and coroutine).

I know it's not something important to have, but it might be good to know for creating DSL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are trying to call a suspend function in a non-suspend lambda. Make lambda in applyLaunch suspend `block: suspend T.() -> Unit`

Comment: It's better to make `applyLaunch` `inline` as well.

Comment: Nice, it does work!

`inline fun <T: ViewModel> T.applyLaunch(crossinline block: suspend T.() -> Unit)`

Is there any real benefit of using inline in such a small function?

Comment: `inline` benefits almost any higher-order function, because it prevents a wrapper class from being instantiated for the lambda.